# PPA build recipes? (AUR's pkgbuild equivalent)

Tags: ppa, launchpad

Is there an equivalent of Arch Linux AUR's pkgbuild for PPAs? ie. a build recipe.

For instance, is there a way to find out how these packages were built [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) ?

I've been looking through launchpad, but can't seem to find it.

Thanks

Comment: What is a build recipe? Is it like creating your own deb package from PPA source?

Comment: Not sure it's the correct term, but basically knowing how a package from a PPA has been built.

For example, in the Arch User Repository the pkgbuild (eg. https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=joplin) easily allows someone to inspect how a package has been built and what changes the package will perform on the system.

Comment: Download the source, and build yourself.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu   (Ubuntu uses Debian packaging (excluding *snaps*) so the build *recipe* follows Debian rules; if you have trouble understanding the Ubuntu wiki pages, just use the Debian ones as it's identical except for regular alternate wording)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if I can summarize. You need a minimum knowledge about Debian packaging. Whenever, you face an idiom while reading this, just go [here for reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/).

Here is a Quick start

1. `.deb` are Debian binary package
2. On PPA or Source repositories you may find two types of Debian source archive

   - Native: `debian` folder included with source (packaging is part of upstream project), so download the source archive `name_version.tar.xz`
   - Foreign: `debian` folder is outside the source tree (packaging is not part of upstream project and source was just imported by the packager). Then download packaging files in separate archive `name_version.debian.tar.xz`
3. You find all build and packing meta and script in `debian`. Two things are important in there.

   - `rules` file: is the main building script (type: GNU `make`). However, it is not quiet easy because most of steps are usually abstracted and automatic orchestrated. By a tool called `debhelper`, `dh` for short.

     So you find just these lines in it (this is for a c/c++ project):

     ```
     #!/usr/bin/make -f

     %:
         dh $@
     ```

     This is a short for pass every operation to `dh`. You may find here some custom compilation flags & options.
   - `debian/patches` folder: contains the patches applied before build, these patches are not merged to upstream project yet or just specific for distribution.
4. A single source archive can be built into multiple binary packages. The build is sliced using `debian/binaryname.install` files. More info about binary packages to be generated, check `debian/control`.

Hope this enough for you to start.

You will find them when you follow [View package details](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers/+packages) link on PPA page.